# Android WebView - get url redirected to, without loading the page in the webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to access a.com, which in turn redirects me to b.com and loads it in the webview.

How do I just get the address that a.com redirects to without loading anything in the webview?

```
String postData = "session=" + session;
    webView.postUrl(urlPassedFromArguments,
            EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {

            if (isAdded() && getActivity() != null)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Logger.e("onPageFinished url", url);

            if (!resolvedUrlLoaded) {
                String postData = "token=" + token;
                webView.postUrl(url,
                        EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
                resolvedUrlLoaded = true;
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
    // url to be loaded
    return true|false;
}
```

> Returns True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

Comment: how can I obtain the redirect-to url using this?

Comment: This method gets called everytime *before* an URL will be loaded. So I guess you got all URLs there, including the redirect-to one. What's it your question?

Comment: also, I read in the documentation that "This method is not called for requests using the POST "method"." - what does that mean? Should I NOT call it when using POST (I am using POST) or it will not be called when I am using POST

Comment: It won't be called when using POST, just you can still override it.

Comment: so do I just add that method in the body of the anonymous WebClient along with those two methods that I am overriding?

Comment: Yes. You'll see all URLs going throw there *before* getting loaded. You can intercept any and do any logic you want then (mind the return value).

Comment: Doesnt work, doesnt get called at all. I read on the net and some guy said that it only gets called if the user manually clicks a link. Cant I just ping the url somehow and see what it returns?

Comment: You can do a request with `HttpURLConnection`, check `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` for "301 Redirect" and use `httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location")` to get the redirection URL for example.

Comment: I will try that, thanks :) This seems as if it will do the job